# How to disable CheckedListBox but enable scrolling winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I know that the question might seems to easy, but I can't find solution. I have CheckdListBox in my form. I have list of checkboxes inside. If I do that:`clbxMyControl.Enabled = false;` then I can't scroll to see all items. How to allow scrolling on disabled CheckedListBox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the user from checking items with the ItemCheck event:

```
    bool listEnabled = true;

    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
        if (!listEnabled) e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
    }
```

But do make sure that it is obvious that checking no longer works:

```
    private void setListEnabled(bool enabled) {
        listEnabled = enabled;
        if (listEnabled) checkedListBox1.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Window);
        else checkedListBox1.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how to change checkboxes label color in CheckdListBox ?

Comment: Click the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of disabling the control you should change it's `SelectionMode` like this:

```
checkedListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
```

The user won't be able to select an item but will be allowed to scroll

Comment: I have already tried to use selection mode property. It does not work for me. I set it in to none and never change.

Comment: I got exception - Multi-selection is not supported on CheckedListBox.

Comment: checkedListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;

Comment: Leave the control enabled: `checkedListBox1.Enabled = true;`

Comment: I did it. But now I can check and uncheck checkboxes... :(

Comment: The idea is like this: leave enabled true for the control and set selectionmode = none when you don't want the user to check and then change selectionmode to One when you want to allow him to check

Comment: I understand. I have set selectionmode propery in designer and did not change it in code. I set enable to true. It does not work.

Comment: Might be you know how to disable checkboxes inside checkedlistbox?

Answer (score 2):

The ListBox has only one handle in the Windows API which is set to enabled or disabled. Therefore there is no native way to enable the scrolling but the items.

You might be able to build your own control that has the requested behavior but you will have to paint it your self from scratch which might be a lot of work or you find a third party control that supports the behavior.

Or you can not use the enabled property but change the background/font color to make it look disabled and set:

```
checkedListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
```

Another alternative might be the DataGridView. It is much more powerful, I'm not sure if it disables the scrollbar, too but if it does you are able to make the cells readonly and color them.

Comment: I have already tried to use selection mode property. It does not work for me. I set it in to none and never change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to make CheckedListBox scrollable.

```
clbxMyControl.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
```

Because Enable=false; make control unscrollable because this make the container of checkbox disabled.

Comment: I have already tried to use selection mode property. It does not work for me. I set it in to none and never change.